# Use select with has_many in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

A `Publication` may cite several other Publications using a has_many association through a join class `Citation`.  So from any Publication I can see publications it cites, and publications it is cited by.

I want to add and delete a given publication's citations within Active Admin, using a selector within a has_many.  The input for the selector is a hash of all Publication titles, and their ids.  There are hundreds of publications to select from, so checkboxes are inappropriate.

Displaying cited/citing publications, and deleting citations, work fine.  When I try to add a new cited Publication, I get:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Admin::PublicationsController#update
Couldnt find Publication with ID=10 for Publication with ID=2

# Extracted source
def raise_nested_attributes_record_not_found!(association_name, record_id)
  raise RecordNotFound, "Couldn't find #{self.class._reflect_on_association(association_name).klass.name} with ID=#{record_id} for #{self.class.name} with ID=#{id}"
end

# Params (edited)
{
    "publication"=>{
      "cited_publications_attributes"=>{
        "0"=>{"id"=>"7", "_destroy"=>"0"},
        "1"=>{"id"=>"10"}
      }},
    "id"=>"2"
 }
```

where 10 is the newly-added (cited) publication, and 2 is the current publication.  Publication 7 is already cited by publication 2.  I don't know why it is searching for Publication 10, which is an already-existing record.

Here's my code:

**models/publication.rb**

```
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :citations
  has_many :cited_publications, :through => :citations
  has_many :inverse_citations, :class_name => "Citation", :foreign_key => "cited_publication_id"
  has_many :citing_publications, :through => :inverse_citations, :source => :publication

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cited_publications, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**models/citation.rb**

```
class Citation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :publication
  belongs_to :cited_publication, :class_name => "Publication"
end
```

**db/migrations/create_citations.rb**

```
class CreateCitations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :citations do |t|
      t.references :publication      , index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :cited_publication, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
 end
```

**admin/publication.rb**

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Publication do
  config.sort_order = 'name_asc'
  permit_params :name,
    cited_publications_attributes:    [:id, :name, :_destroy]

  show do
    span b 'Cites: '
    span raw publication.cited_publications.map{ |p| link_to(p.name, admin_publication_path(p)) }.join(", ")
    br
    span b 'Cited by: '
    span raw publication.citing_publications.map{ |p| link_to(p.name, admin_publication_path(p)) }.join(", ")
  end

  form do |f|
    inputs 'Details' do
      publications = Publication.order(:name).map { |p| [p.name, p.id] }
      f.has_many :cited_publications, allow_destroy: true, heading: 'Cited Publications', new_record: 'Add cited publication:' do |c|
        c.input :id, as: :select, collection: publications, label: "Cites", include_blank: false
      end
    end
    br
    actions
  end
end
```

Help?  I've been stuck on this for many hours.

Comment: Ok, so it's looking for the newly-added publication 10 as a cited_publication off your main publication and failing to find it. The code that seems to do this... is in the show action. I am totally guessing, but perhaps after adding the publication correctly, it's running the show-code and hasn't reloaded the association yet, so it's not showing up as a publication? Check whether this is the case by a) reloading in the show action b) puts-ing the list of cited_publications in same... note: probably wrong, just a first guess based on what failing and the code you provided

Comment: Thanks for the lead which I followed, but didn't find anything there.  What I did in the end was to change my `has_many` from `:cited_publications` with an input of `id` (the target of the join), to `:citations` with an input of `cited_publication_id`.  So I'm creating a join table record rather than having it created for me. This seems to work though having to specify an id rather than object usually means I'm doing it wrong.